# How to apply a Coupon Code on a Stripe subscription using laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I applied a discount code to a subscription but it gives me this error:

> [2021-08-13 08:06:49] local.INFO: No such coupon: 'mycode' for
> subscription plan Oro User Name: hmza khan Id:23

The code is as bellow:

```
$abc  = $user->newSubscription('default', $plan->plan_id)
        ->withCoupon($request->coupon)
        ->create($paymentMethod, [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);
```

I created a coupon in Stripe a/c on this link

```
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/coupons
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjttl.png)

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: This error No such coupon: 'mycode' for subscription plan Oro User Name: hmza khan Id:23

Comment: please double check if the coupon is created or check the valid flag on the coupon

Comment: if the coupon exists, please add coupon JSON to the answer

Comment: how can i send you screenshot of my stripetest a/c where i create coupon

Comment: whats the value of $request->coupon?

Comment: value is same i give.. like i create testcoupon and value is same testcoupon.. i also give direct value in controller and gives same error..  auth()->user()->newSubscription('default', $plan->plan_id)
            ->withCoupon($request->coupon)
            ->create($paymentMethod);

Comment: withCoupon('testcoupon') still error is same

Comment: i didnot see any flag on coupon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to provide the coupon ID available from the Stripe Dashboard. This is usually generated automatically but you can provide a custom id which you can pass on to your customers as well and the same can be captured against a payment.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2OCP.png: View Coupon ID

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADyq4.png: How to create custom coupon ID.

Comment: i am facing one issue in stripe on live mode.. can you tell me the solution.. actually it works fine when on test mode but on live mode when on click button 3dsecure popup open after verification it close then it not further run .. even not go in method you can find this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322782/stripe-on-test-mode-works-fine-but-on-live-mode-it-does-not-work-in-laravel